# Keeping 'key' column when using groupby with transform in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Finding a normalized dataframe removes the column being used to group by, so that it can't be used in subsequent groupby operations.  for example (edit: updated):

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1 , 2, 3, 2, 3], 'b':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

       a  b
    0  1  0
    1  1  1
    2  2  2
    3  3  3
    4  2  4
    5  3  5

    df.groupby('a').transform(lambda x: x)

       b
    0  0
    1  1
    2  2
    3  3
    4  4
    5  5
```

Now, with most operations on groups the 'missing' column becomes a new index (which can then be adjusted using `reset_index`, or set `as_index=False`), but when using transform it just disappears, leaving the original index and a new dataset without the key.

Edit: here's a one liner of what I would like to be able to do

```
    df.groupby('a').transform(lambda x: x+1).groupby('a').mean()
    KeyError 'a'
```

In the example from the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) a function is used to split based on the index, which appears to avoid this issue entirely.  Alternatively, it would always be possible just to add the column after the groupby/transform, but surely there's a better way?

Update:
It looks like reset_index/as_index are intended only for functions that reduce each group to a single row.  There seem to be a couple options, from answers

Comment: Your end-goal isn't very clear... Would adding a new __virtual__ column on the fly solve your issue: `df.assign(new=df.groupby('a').transform('sum'))`?

Comment: The overall issue is that I need to groupby column 'a' several times, so any solution that allows that.

Comment: @MaxU, That looks like a possible approach, although in this case I'm applying the transform to more than one column.

Comment: Can you post bit more detailed question / example? Now your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me

Comment: It is a bit of that.  The pandas docs suggest several ways to keep an index (reset_index, as_index=False), which led me into thinking this would be the correct approach to re-using the index.  Really, it's easier just to reuse the original index on subsequent groupby's, since the transform function modifies the index column even if it is kept.

Comment: for this particular question (in Edit): `df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: (x.b+1).mean())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is bizzare!

I tricked it like this

```
df.groupby(df.a.values).transform(lambda x: x)
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately it's not that easy... Try this: `df.groupby(df.a.values).transform('sum')`

Comment: I like this. It's up to the transform to keep the actual values (so builtins like mean will change it), but it can still be used to create the same groups in subsequent groupby's.

Answer (score 15):

The issue is discussed also [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12495).

The returned object has the same indices as the original df, therefore you can do

```
pd.concat([
    df['a'],
    df.groupby('a').transform(lambda x: x)
], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve something similiar to what Pepacz suggested:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.drop('a')] = df.groupby('a').transform(lambda x: x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['b'] = df.groupby('a').transform(lambda x: x)
df.drop_duplicates()
```