# Get the groupby column back in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a groupby on column `a` followed by `ffill`, but after groupby the column `a` is gone. The result df will have only column `b` and `c`. Is there a way to get the column `a` back after groupby and ffill? I am assuming that the values will shuffle in the process.

How to get back the groupby column in pandas?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2] ,  
                   'b': [12,np.nan,14, 13], 
                   'c' : [1, 2, np.nan, np.nan]
                 })
df

df.groupby('a').ffill()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40139184/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2] ,  
                   'b': [12,np.nan,14, 13], 
                   'c' : [1, 2, np.nan, np.nan]
                 })

df[['b', 'c']] = df.groupby('a').ffill()

print(df)
```

```
   a     b    c
0  1  12.0  1.0
1  1  12.0  2.0
2  2  14.0  NaN
3  2  13.0  NaN
```

Comment: I was of the impression that groupby shuffle the data but looks like it does not. Thanks for solution

Answer (score 0):

This will *work*...

```
df.groupby('a').ffill().join(df.a)[['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

I'm not sure why the column disappears when `groupby` returns a like-indexed (transform) result.  For example, `cumsum` has the same issue. I thought it might be related to the `group_keys` argument of `groupby`, but I didn't have any luck when setting that to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can force to have all columns with:

```
df.groupby('a')[list(df)].ffill()

# or
df.groupby('a')[df.columns].ffill()

# or
df.groupby(df['a'].to_numpy()).ffill()
```

Output:

```
   a     b    c
0  1  12.0  1.0
1  1  12.0  2.0
2  2  14.0  NaN
3  2  13.0  NaN
```